# MySQL query optimization to minimize the run time

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I need to optimize the below query in MySQL.

The base table "A" has around 994 million records.

Is there a way to modify the not in clause as exist clause does not work with MySQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.Cola1 AS Col1
FROM
    db.tableA a
        INNER JOIN
    db.tableB b ON a.cola2 = b.colb1
        INNER JOIN
    db.tableC c ON b.colb2 = c.colc1
WHERE
    (c.colc2 = 2 OR (c.colc2 = 7047 AND a.cola3 = '04250'))
        AND a.Col1 NOT IN (334394 , 334223, 334222, 305669)
ORDER BY a.Col1
```

Comment: *Is there a way to modify the not in clause as exist clause does not work with MySQL* , `EXISTS` works just fine with MySQL. Please post table description (show create table table_name) , execution plan all in text format. Would be better to post some data example and expected result , query might be written differently .

Comment: Divide OR condition, use two subqueries and UNION ALL.

Comment: Even the UNION takes similar time as the distinct one. The tableA has around 990 million records.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 suggestions (made without provided sample data). Neither of these use joins and hence `select distinct` should now be redundant. It isn't known if either suggestion will actually improve performance - you need to test for this (use explain plans).

```
SELECT a.Cola1 AS Col1
FROM tableA a
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM tableB b
        WHERE a.cola2 = b.colb1 
        AND EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM tableC c
                WHERE b.colb2 = c.colc1 AND (c.colc2 = 2 OR (c.colc2 = 7047 AND a.cola3 = '04250'))
                )
        ) 
AND a.Cola1 NOT IN (334394, 334223, 334222, 305669)
ORDER BY a.Cola1;


SELECT a.Cola1 AS Col1
FROM tableA a
WHERE a.Cola2 IN (
        SELECT colb1
        FROM tableB b
        WHERE EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM tableC c
                WHERE b.colb2 = c.colc1 AND (c.colc2 = 2 OR (c.colc2 = 7047 AND a.Cola3 = '04250'))
                )
        ) 
AND a.Cola1 NOT IN (334394, 334223, 334222, 305669)
ORDER BY a.Cola1;
```

working examples here at [db-fiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/FfWkqMsn)

Note indexing your tables appropriately can substantially improve query performance. e.g:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_tableA_cola2_Cola1 ON db.tableA(cola2, Cola1);
CREATE INDEX idx_tableA_Cola1 ON db.tableA(Cola1);
CREATE INDEX idx_tableB_colb1_colb2 ON db.tableB(colb1, colb2);
CREATE INDEX idx_tableC_colc1_colc2 ON db.tableC(colc1, colc2);
```

- idx_tableA_cola2_Cola1 index to assist lookup of cola2 in an EXISTS subquery.
- idx_tableA_Cola1 index for the NOT IN operation in the WHERE clause.
- idx_tableB_colb1_colb2 index may help speed a join between tableA and tableB (if used).
- idx_tableC_colc1_colc2 index for subquery on tableC.

Comment: Sure, let me test it out. Thanks for the response.